# Python shlex.split() cannot retain single quotes

Tags: python, regex, split, lex, shlex

I have the following text:

```
'sudo -S java -cp spinn3r-client-3.4.06.jar com.spinn3r.api.Main --vendor=test --remote-filter=\'(and (eq source:publisher_type " WEBLOG") (eq dc_lang:English) \''
```

Now I need to split this to run using the subprocess module. I tried using shlex.split. I got the following:

```
['sudo',
 '-S',
 'java',
 '-cp',
 'spinn3r-client-3.4.06.jar',
 'com.spinn3r.api.Main',
 '--vendor=test',
 '--remote-filter=(and (eq source:publisher_type " WEBLOG") (eq dc_lang:English) ']
```

As you can see, the single quotes after --remote-filter are being removed. I need these single quotes in my text. How do I go about preserving these quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Even though it strips off the single quotes, it appears to be interpreted fine when using `subprocess`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# > someScript
echo ${1} # sudo
echo ${2} # -S
echo ${3} # --vendor=test
echo ${4} # --remote-filter=(simple) (<--space-->)
echo ${5} # --foo
echo ${6} # bar
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess, shlex

subprg = (
    './someScript sudo -S --vendor=test '
    '--remote-filter=\'(simple) (<--space-->) \' --foo bar')

subprocess.call(shlex.split(subprg))
```

An alternative is to directly pass in the text but there are some [security issues](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) with it.

```py
subprocess.call('./someScript sudo -S ...', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a `shlex` issue: posix shell does also consume the single quotes in effect:

```
user@debi:~$ python -c "import sys;print sys.argv" sudo -S java -cp spinn3r-client-3.4.06.jar com.spinn3r.api.Main --vendor=test --remote-filter='(and (eq source:publisher_type " WEBLOG") (eq dc_lang:English) '
['-c', 'sudo', '-S', 'java', '-cp', 'spinn3r-client-3.4.06.jar', 'com.spinn3r.api.Main', '--vendor=test', '--remote-filter=(and (eq source:publisher_type " WEBLOG") (eq dc_lang:English) ']
```

The quotes purpose is just to get the spaces of the *remote-filter* argument through. So its ok for your use-case as it is.

If you really want to get the single quotes into a sub-process, then extra quoting/escaping is necessary:

```
user@debi:~$ python -c "import sys;print sys.argv" sudo -S java -cp spinn3r-client-3.4.06.jar com.spinn3r.api.Main --vendor=test --remote-filter="'(and (eq source:publisher_type \" WEBLOG\") (eq dc_lang:English) '" 
['-c', 'sudo', '-S', 'java', '-cp', 'spinn3r-client-3.4.06.jar', 'com.spinn3r.api.Main', '--vendor=test', '--remote-filter=\'(and (eq source:publisher_type " WEBLOG") (eq dc_lang:English) \'']
```