# shlex.split() : How to keep quotes around sub-strings and not split by in-sub-string whitespace?

Tags: python, parsing, text-parsing, shlex

I want the input string `"add [7,8,9+5,'io open'] 7&4 67"` to be split like `['add', "[7,8,9+5,'io open']", '7&4', '67']`, i.e, within the line, strings must remain within quotes and musn't be split at all , and otherwise whitespace based splitting is required, like so :

```py
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split("add [7,8,9+5,\\'io\\ open\\'] 7&4 67")
['add', "[7,8,9+5,'io open']", '7&4', '67']
```

But the user shouldn't have to use the `\\` if possible, at least not for quotes but if possible not for in-string whitespace too.

What would a function `break_down()` that does the above look like ? I attempted the below, but it doesn't deal with in-string whitespace :

```py
>>> import shlex
>>> def break_down(ln) :
...     ln = ln.replace("'","\\'")
...     ln = ln.replace('"','\\"')
...     # User will still have to escape in-string whitespace
...     return shlex.split(ln) # Note : Can't use posix=False; will split by in-string whitespace and has no escape seqs
...
>>> break_down("add [7,8,9+5,'io\\ open'] 7&4 67")
['add', "[7,8,9+5,'io open']", '7&4', '67']
>>> break_down("add [7,8,9+5,'io open'] 7&4 67")
['add', "[7,8,9+5,'io", "open']", '7&4', '67']
```

Maybe be there's a better function/method/technique to do this, I'm not very experienced with the entire standard library yet. Or maybe I'll just have to write a custom `split()` ?

EDIT 1 : Progress

```py
>>> def break_down(ln) :
...     ln = r"{}".format(ln) # escape sequences don't require \\
...     ln = ln.replace("'",r"\'")
...     ln = ln.replace('"',r'\"')
...     return shlex.split(ln)
```

So now the user only has to use a single `\` to escape any quotes/spaces etc , kind of like they would in a shell. Seems workable.

Comment: `shlex.split('add [7,8,9+5,\\'io\\ open\\'] 7&4 67')` gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Epsi95 my bad, corrected that

Comment: don't understand your question fully, what is the problem with `shlex.split("add [7,8,9+5,'io open'] 7&4 67")` ?

Comment: @Epsi it results in `['add', '[7,8,9+5,io open]', '7&4', '67']` but I need the string `io open` to remain in quotes

Comment: oh okay, understood your problem, FYI did u check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684937/python-shlex-split-cannot-retain-single-quotes `Even though it strips off the single quotes, it appears to be interpreted fine when using subprocess`

Comment: @Epsi95 That's a nice note but I'm directly parsing and evaluating user input, this string is being used to make changes to a database (this is a dbms in py3 ) and the elements will be passed to a `safe_eval()`, meaning without the strings in quotes I'll get a `NameError`, as `io open != 'io open'`

Comment: idk how much it will be helpful but you can try regex `[re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z\s]+)', r"'\1'", i) if '[' in i else i for i in shlex.split("add [7,8,9+5,'io open'] 7&4 67")]` after `import re`

Comment: `shlex` is a parser which gives correct result if `" "` is not inside longer text - ie. `shlex.split('add "io open" 7&4 67', posix=False)` gives `['add', '"io open"', '7&4', '67']`. Maybe you should write own parser using ie. [SLY](https://github.com/dabeaz/sly) or [PLY](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply)

Comment: @Epsi95 Sure, that is actually helpful, but i don't want the whitespace seperation to occur inside *any string at all* , not just inside strings enclosed within `[]`... If you could help me with the re for such a case, that can be an accepted answer and would be highly helpful. Meanwhile I'll try to learn re

Comment: @furas writing my own parser should be the ideal perfect solution. Unfortunately, I have some time and effort constraints on the project, though I may later revisit the idea and implement one.

Comment: I get correct result also for `"add \"[7,8,9+5,'io open']\" 7&4 67"` - it still need to add extra chars `\"` but it seems simpler and more readable then your `"add [7,8,9+5,\\'io\\ open\\'] 7&4 67"` and you could use `ln = ln.replace('[', '"[').replace(']', ']"')`. But if you have other data ie, `{ }` then it would need more code.

Comment: @furas but why would the list be declared within quotes ? To the user, he is entering a list, not a string. Update : now with the last edit `"add [7,8,9+5,'io\ open'] 7&4 67"` works, with the simple rule seeming to be that any spaces need to be escaped with a ```\```

Comment: `quotes` informs shlex that it has to treat it as one string and then it doesn't split it. Frankly, normally this method is popular in shell (`bash`) to inform shell that it has to treat it as single element and not split it.

Comment: BTW: this method you can have more spaces in data ie. `"add \"[ 7, 8, 9+5, 'io open' ]\" 7&4 67"` and it will return it as single element `[ 7, 8, 9+5, 'io open' ]`

Comment: @furas interesting , that's quite promising

Comment: and you can use it when you generate command like `data = [7,8,9+5,'io open']` and `f"add \"{data}\" 7&4 67"`

Comment: @furas what is your opinion on my new solution ( posted as a self-answer) ? Thanks !

Comment: @Epsi95 As it stands currently, my new solution uses `re` for lexing and foregoes `shlex` entirely, I'd appreciate your opinion on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this like I should have, by writing a custom lexing system (sort of).

I decided to use `re`, because the code uses `re` a lot all over anyways, and with help from [this reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/regex/comments/optrvc/noob_needs_help_with_parsingtokenising_with_regex/h680lyp?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) , have settled on this :

```py
def lex(ln):
    ln = ln.split('#')[0] # Strip comments
    
    tkn_delims, relst = '\'\'""{}()[]',[] # Edit tkn_delims to add more delimiters  
    for i in range(0,len(tkn_delims),2):
        # Add regex for delimiter
        relst.append(r'\{0}[^{1}]*\{1}'.format(tkn_delims[i],tkn_delims[i+1])) 
    regex = '|'.join(relst) + r'|\S+' # Build regex
    
    import re
    return re.findall(regex,ln)
```

---

Edit : Thanks to @furas 's comment : "*first reaction: you can't use # in arguments...*" , code edited to only recognise start of comment if `#` appears as 1st element of a token . Thus :

- `<command> '#...' ['#...#']` lexes to `['command',"'#...'","['#...#']"]`
- `<command> '...' # does xyz` or `<command> '...' #does xyz` lexes to `['<command>',"'...'"]`.

Edited `lex()` :

```py
def lex(ln) :
    ''' Lexing :
    1. Generate regex for each token type :
       a) tokens that are python sequence literals.
       b) tokens that are whitespace delimited. 
       There is only one 'layer' of lexing,i.e in case of sequences within sequences, the entire outermost sequence is one token.
     2. Remove tokens that fall into comments
     3. Return list of tokens
    '''

    token_delims = '\'\'""{}()[]'
    regex_subexperessions = [] 
    for i in range(0,len(token_delims),2) :
        regex_subexperessions.append(r'\{0}[^{1}]*\{1}'.format(token_delims[i],token_delims[i+1])) # Regex for each sequence delimiter pair
    regex = '|'.join(regex_subexperessions) + r'|\S+'                                       # Combine with regex for whitespace delimitation on the remainder

    tokens = re.findall(regex,ln)
    comment = False
    for token in  tokens :
        if comment : tokens.remove(token)
        elif token[0] == '#' : comment = True

    return tokens
```

Comment: first reaction: you can't use `#` in arguments `lex("add [7,8,9+5,'#io open'] 7&4 67")` :)  But if this resolves all your other problems then is OK

Comment: @furas thanks for this, you spotted something very important !